# What's wrong with my query and what does the error mean?

Tags: sqlite, inner-join

I cannot figure what's wrong with this query and what the error means:

Query

```
select Total2014, Total2015
From 2014_Jan_Pivot
inner join 2015_Jan_Pivot on 2014_Jan_Pivot.PremiseCity2014= 
2015_Jan_Pivot.PremiseCity2015
```

> Error says:
>   unrecognized token: "2014_Jan_Pivot": select Total2014, Total2015, Total2016, Total2017
>   From 2014_Jan_Pivot

Comment: It worked!Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because names in SQLite cannot start with a digit/number unless they are enclosed.

So **2014_Jan_Pivot** is an invalid (aka unrecognised) token.

However, you can enclose the name and it will then be recognised e.g. :-

```
[2014_Jan_Pivot] 
`2014_Jan_Pivot`
"2014_Jan_Pivot" or
'2014_Jan_Pivot'
```

So your query could be :-

```
SELECT 
    Total2014, 
    Total2015 
FROM [2014_Jan_Pivot] 
    INNER JOIN [2015_Jan_Pivot] ON 
        [2014_Jan_Pivot].PremiseCity2014 = [2015_Jan_Pivot].PremiseCity2015
```

Comment: One method [is correct standard SQL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html); the other three are just supported for bug compatibility with other DBs.